# Efficient way to work with multiple arrays in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a puzzle game in Flash/AS3. It uses about 30 to 40 groups of words. What I want to do is to load one random group of words in the beginning of the game and after using them, I want to load another random group and so on. What is the best way to solve this? Should I have multiple arrays which I will select from using switch statement based on random number or should I put them all into one multidimensional array? Every group of words could contain up to 2000 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better you use xml for creating wordgroups and to pull them easily. So, i mean, it's efficient you use multidimensional arrays.

```
var wordgroups:Array = new Array();
wordgroups.push(new Array("word1", "word3", "word5"), new Array("word2", "word4", "word6")); //you can easily create whole this multidimensional array with xml

wordgroups.shuffle(); //shuffles array (flashpunk library have this function, you may check it out and clone it's function if you can)

var selectedwordgroup:Array;
selectedwordgroup = wordgroups.pop(); //you can easily take a word group from that array and it removes selected wordgroup from the "wordgroups" array automatically with pop() function.
```

What about XML stuff

Thats a sample *.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wordstuff>
   <wordgroups>
      <group>word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6</group>
      <group>word7,word8,word9,word10,word11,word12</group>
      <group>word13,word14,word15,word16,word17,word18</group>
   </wordgroups>
</wordstuff>
```

and this is a sample to pull data from xml (you're going to embed your xml stuff to your game, so, you don't need any url loader object, you can embed it like you're embedding image files into your game, with a little difference)
then you can create arrays with this embedded xml

```
var pulledgroups:Array = new Array();

var my_xml:XML = WORDSTUFF //that's embedded file
var wordgroups:XMLList = my_xml.wordgroups.group;
var group:XML;
for each (group in wordgroups)
{
   var pulledwordgroup:Array = group.split(",");
   pulledgroups.push(pulledwordgroup);
}
```

THAT'S ALL, this single code paragraph, pulls all data at the same time

Comment: but it's better you don't use "shuffle" stuff, your way makes better performance, i mean using random numbers & taking random array from wordgroups...

Comment: And how do I create those arrays from XML?

Comment: it's so easy, i'll add a little example to my answer, just a minute

Comment: it's done... check it out... also, there is little embedding issue, you need that:

`[Embed(source="wordstuff.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]public const WORDSTUFF:Class;`