# Actionscript 3 - Parsing an XML file to load assets

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm fairly new to file loading in Flash and while i'm used to the ease and comfort of C#'s serialization for xml file, i'm completely lost with how I need to approach this in Flash. I have two types of xml files I need to be able to load and I was hoping you could help me set up my code properly!

Lets start with the first xml file. It will look something like this (with more Level elements in later on):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Level>
    <filepath>../Assets/Level.xml</filepath>
  </Level>
</Root>
```

And the code to load it is below

```
public function loadLevelFilePaths():void
{
    trace("Loading XML");
    var XMLData:XML = new XML(new URLRequest("../Assets/LevelFilePaths.xml"));

    for each (var node:XML in XMLData.Level)
    {
        levelFilePaths.push(node.filepath.text());
        trace("Level " + levelFilePaths[levelFilePaths.length - 1] + " loaded!");
    }
}
```

The second type of XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Level xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <level>
    <Room>
      <tiles />
      <IsEmpty>true</IsEmpty>
    </Room>
  </level>
</Level>
```

For the sake of space, I didn't include the largest possible room, but the tiles node could contain up to about 100 "Tiles" each with their own set of data and there could be up to 100 Rooms inside of this level.

I haven't yet written the code to load this because I don't quite understand how to load the simple xml file I posted above.

If someone would be willing to also explain how this process works in Flash, I would also be grateful!

Comment: Using XML in flash easier... Check this out...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737622/efficient-way-to-work-with-multiple-arrays-in-as3/21738262#21738262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load an xml file, you can use a URLLoader to load the data as a String, then pass that to the XML constructor.

Note that it's typically a good idea to put a try/catch around new XML in order to catch malformed xml.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("LevelFilePaths.xml"));

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoadCompleteHandler);

function dataLoadCompleteHandler(event:Event) {
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.currentTarget);

    var xml:XML;
    try {
            // urlLoader.data contains the file contents as a String. 
        xml = new XML(urlLoader.data); 
    } catch (e:Error) {
        trace("The xml was malformed.");
    }

    if (xml) {
        trace("XML Loaded");
        for each (var level in xml.level) {
            for each (var room in level.Room) {
                trace("Room: " + room.toXMLString());
                trace("is empty: " + room.IsEmpty.text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason i'm getting an unhandled exception when trying to load the file. The error is as follows:

Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/LevelFilePaths.xml

Comment: "LevelFilePaths.xml" is the filename of the .xml relative to your application.

Comment: yes i'm aware. I changed it to the proper file path and it still crashed. I also moved the file to make that the proper filepath but it still refuses to work. :/

Comment: I was able to fix my problem. For whatever reason, the filepath I used was wrong (even though a similar filepath is working fine for other assets). Thanks!